# Adding a "Difficulty Level" to  a tutorial blog post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I'm creating a WordPress theme that will have general articles and tutorials. The tutorials will look like the rest of the articles, but with one difference: they'll begin with a box containing info like "difficulty level: beginner" or "tools required: Photoshop."

I'm somewhat new to WordPress and I'm hoping someone can help me understand the "right way" or best practices for something like this. I'm tempted to just hard code this info at the top of each tutorial. From what I can tell, other solutions would involve conditional template tags, alternate single-article templates, custom fields, etc. While I'm not averse to trying any of those, I wonder if it's the way to go.

Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: You are *creating* a theme, so you have a fair knowledge of PHP, right?

Comment: "Fair knowledge" may be overstating it a bit. I'm familiar enough with PHP and WordPress template tags to feel that I can create a basic theme from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use tags?

Taxonomies are probably be the easiest way to categorize each tutorial.

Tags are also included in menu creation (APPEARANCE > MENUS).

So, for example, if you needed to create a menu item for just "Beginners", all articles tagged with beginners would be listed.

Also you can show all the tags in a tag cloud widget which are built into WordPress as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think @manonatelier suggestion is perfect in the context of your question.

In case you want to deal with Custom Fields and Meta Boxes take a look at this class for theme developers [Custom Metaboxes and Fields for WordPress](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress).